# Delete the rows which has duplicate columns

Tags: mysql

My table `corpus` is like this
I want to delete the row which include duplicated `text` and remain 1 row.

```
id, text,         genre1,   genre2
1   my name is    1         0
2   yeyyeyyey!    0         1
3   my name is    1         0      // delete
4   hello         1         0      
5   I am a ..     1         1
6   my name is    1         1      // delete
7   hello         0         0      // delete
```

I googled around and made sql like this ,but it shows error when making temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE corpus_tmp AS SELECT text,genre1,genre2 FROM corpus GROUP BY text;
TRUNCATE corpus;
INSERT INTO corpus SELECT * FROM corpus_tmp;
DROP TABLE corpus_tmp;
```

these are error message

```
#1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mydata.corpus.genre1' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I added the article.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - your `temporary table` creation is okay, problem was the query as you've used group by , you need to add all columns in `group by clause` or need to use `aggregation`

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE corpus_tmp AS 
SELECT * 
FROM corpus c where id in (select min(id) from corpus c1 where c.text=c1.text) 
TRUNCATE corpus;
INSERT INTO corpus SELECT * FROM corpus_tmp;
DROP TABLE corpus_tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
delete c2 from corpus c1 inner join corpus c2 where c1.id < c2.id and c1.text = c2.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM corpus
    WHERE id NOT IN
        (SELECT * FROM 
             (SELECT MIN(a.id) FROM corpus a GROUP BY a.text)
        b)
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE new_corpus AS
SELECT a.*
  FROM corpus a
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) id FROM corpus GROUP BY `text`) b
    ON b.id = a.id;
```

Comment: smart answer, btw

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. I use the method "Select then delete".
2. Tag 1 - Use select distinct to get the unique text(text_test) of table corpus
3. Tag 2 - I join again the selected text to table corpus and get the id using the "min()" function so that you select the first id of original text, not the duplicate ids of the original text then group it by b.text_test to get all original ids.
4. Tag 3 - Select only the ids from the previous selection.
5. Tag 4 - You can now delete the duplicates using the "Not in" the selected original ids.

```
    delete from corpus where id not in( /*tag 4 */
    select a.id from ( /* tag 3 */
        select min(b.id) id from ( /* tag 2 */
          select distinct text_test from corpus /* tag 1 */
        ) a
    left outer join corpus b
    on a.text_test = b.text_test
    group by b.text_test) a
    );
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it